# How to add loadmore with text or icon view in Flatlist/ Scrollview react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, lazy-loading, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to add view when user swipe to latest item and have to hard swipe to do action or can see the view.
Like this Tiktok app ([Example](https://giphy.com/gifs/RINCbohMfbntC1HvoI))

Did anyone have any ideas for this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onEndReached` & `onEndReachedThreshold` prop of flatlist.
See here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached